# Combo box causes app to crash when accessed using a touch interface, but works with a mouse

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a combo box that displays a list of repositories on a database, and the only event I have for it is the DropDownOpened event, during which I access the database to get the list of items to display.

Everything works great using a mouse to open the combo box and select an item, but when I use a touch screen (either on windows 8 or surface) there are problems.

The first time I open the combo box and select an there are no issues, but after I've selected an item, if I try to open the list again, the app crashes.

Here is the xaml for the combo box:

```
    <ComboBox x:Name="RepositoryComboBox" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRepository, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding RepositoryList, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"  IsEnabled="True" DropDownOpened="ReposDrop"/>
```

and the code for the drop down opened event:

```
    private async void ReposDrop(object sender, object e)
    {

        ViewModel.RepositoryList = null;
            try
            {
                await ViewModel.GetRepositories(); //accesses database through a WCF service
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return;
            }

    }
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this issue?

**Edit** This is the error I'm getting

```
    Exception   {"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."}
```

Comment: It seems that if the repository list contained no elements the app would crash, so adding a dummy element to the empty lists solved the problem.   No idea why it had this issue or why it only crashed when using touch input.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your `ViewModel.GetRepositories()` call updates the list contents on a background thread. Check if it still crashes if you don't call it. You can also try delaying the call, e.g. with `await Task.Delay(100)` in case the `ComboBox` doesn't like its contents updating while it's opening.

Comment: Is this solved the issue? I am also getting exacpt same error on exacpt same scenario